# php search function with sql

Tags: php, sql, search

I am working on a search function. User type the email on the search box and the matching email on the database will show on the drop down while i am typing. 
I know how to search the database, or a normal search function such like input key word, then click the button, show the result on the next page. I want to know if there is anyway i can make it look like google search box which the matching result will show in a drop down menu while i am typing. It is easy to create a drop down menu with html with some options that I already put in the code, but in this case, i need combine this drop down menu with the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for : https://github.com/dyve/jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Sure, one way of doing this is through a ajax request. You might look into making a javascript ajax request to a php file that can do the sql query for you and return your returns to javascript script that can then update the dom.